# Determining Number of Peaks in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find the number of peaks in Matlab. When I plot the given wav file according to my threshold values, I can easily see that there are two distinct peaks. But how can I write "There are two peaks" on the screen? Here's my first attempt:

```
hfile = 'two.wav';

[stereo1, Fs, nbits, readinfo] = wavread(hfile);
mono1 = mean(stereo1,2);

M = round(0.01*Fs); 
N = 2^nextpow2(4*M);
w = gausswin(M);


[S,F,T,P] = spectrogram(mono1,w,120,N,Fs);

thresh_l=1000;
thresh_h=10000000;
% take the segment of P relating to your frequencies of interest
P2 = P(F>thresh_l&F<thresh_h,:); 

%show the mean power in that band over time
m = mean(P2);
[pks,loc]=findpeaks(T,'npeaks',m);
message = sprintf('The number of peaks found = %d',length(pks));
msgbox(message);
```

Comment: Where on the screen do you want it? In a msgbox that pops up or as a note on the plot itself?

Comment: Both are Ok. Can you add some codes which can write this message?

Answer (score 0):

how about looking for where the first derivative switches sign? say x is your time series

```
dx = diff(x);
% need to add 1 b/c of the offset generated by diff
peak_loc = find((dx(1:end - 1) > 0) & (dx(2:end) <= 0)) + 1;
peak_num = len(peak_loc);
```

Comment: Thank you very much but how can I integrate this code block to my existing code? I have tried but it does not find any peaks?